# SQL merging rows with dynamic column headings

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, pivot, transpose

I am trying to populate a Gridview to have `checkbox`es enabled per student, but depending to certain values from this query:

@SelectedDate is provided via a TextBox as a date only

```
SELECT  v1.StudentID,
        v1.StudentPreferredName + ' ' + v1.StudentFamilyName AS StudentName,
        bcs.CheckStatusName,
        rce.DateSubmitted,
        rcp.RollCallPeriod
FROM tblBoardingRollCallEntries AS rce
     INNER JOIN vwBoardingTenants AS v1
        ON v1.StudentID = rce.StudentID
       AND v1.[Year] = YEAR(@SelectedDate)
     INNER JOIN tblBoardingCheckStatus AS bcs
        ON bcs.CheckStatusID = rce.CheckStatusID
       AND bcs.StatusActive = 1
     INNER JOIN tblBoardingRollCallPeriods AS rcp
         ON rcp.RollCallPeriodID = rce.RollCallPeriodID
        AND rcp.PeriodYear = YEAR(@SelectedDate)
        AND @SelectedDate BETWEEN rcp.PeriodStart AND rcp.PeriodEnd
        AND rcp.RowStatus = 1
WHERE dbo.fnDateOnly(rce.DateSubmitted) = dbo.fnDateOnly(@SelectedDate)
```

My gridview:

Shows the following:

[image]

The data:

[image]

I want to be able to basically condense the rows in the `GridView` to be one student per row and the checkboxes ticked according to `RollCallPeriod` text.

I am playing with SQL pivots, to get the data to be as close as possible to what I am after so as to avoid code-behind, etc. However, I cannot get this to work.

```
select StudentID, [1],[10],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9]
      from
      (
        select StudentID, RollCallID, CheckStatusID
        from tblBoardingRollCallEntries
        unpivot
        (
          value for name in ([RollCallID],[StudentID],[CheckStatusID],[DateSubmitted],[StaffID])
        ) unpiv
      ) src
      pivot
      (
        sum(RollCallPeriodID)
        for RollCallPeriodID in ([1],[10],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9])
      ) piv
```

I receive the following error:

> Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: The type of column
>   "StudentID" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the
>   UNPIVOT list.

Any other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: can you please post sample data instead of images then we can test the code along with data to give  appropriate answer

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic913419-338-1.aspx

Comment: Thanks @mohan111 but the data above is it! Two records showing different Period Times.

Comment: if your first query gets you the data you need you should just be pivoting that data, what is the purpose of the UNPIVOT?

Comment: @JamieD77 Don't know! LOL... I am just playing with SQL Pivots. I got that idea from another forum on how to generate a transpose of data from rows to columns. But I don't think it will work in my case because the student id, and name have to be the rows and the periodtimes have to be the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ways you can do this depending on your actual data.

This will give you the `CheckStatusName` as the value for the `RollCallPeriod`

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT  StudentName,
                    CheckStatusName,
                    RollCallPeriod
            FROM    [YourQueryGoesHere]
        ) t 
PIVOT   ( 
    MAX(CheckStatusName) 
    FOR RollCallPeriod IN ([6:15 AM],[8:00 AM],[3:00 PM],[6:00 PM],[9:00 PM]) 
) p
```

[image]

Or you  get the status and a `COUNT()` to show if that Student has a value for that `CheckStatusName, RollCallPeriod`

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT  StudentName,
                    CheckStatusName,
                    RollCallPeriod
            FROM    [YourQueryGoesHere]
        ) t 
PIVOT   ( 
    COUNT(RollCallPeriod) 
    FOR RollCallPeriod IN ([6:15 AM],[8:00 AM],[3:00 PM],[6:00 PM],[9:00 PM]) 
) p
```

[image]

Comment: Precisely what I was after. Thank you very much. The SQL pivoting just had me so confused. Do you have a good reference for SQL Pivots for dummies? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

---

1. Instead of unpivotting directly on `tblBoardingRollCallEntries`: first select columns cast to a `VARCHAR(...)` type in a derived table, then `UNPIVOT` the derived table. Shortened example:

```
select StudentID, RollCallID, CheckStatusID
from 
(
    SELECT ..., CAST(StudentId AS VARCHAR(128)) AS StudentId, ... FROM tblBoardingRollCallEntries)
) AS ups
unpivot
(
    value for name in ([RollCallID],[StudentID],[CheckStatusID],[DateSubmitted],[StaffID])
) unpiv
```

---

2. Use `CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(StudentId AS VARCHAR(128)) UNION ALL ... )` to unpivot, that way you can UNPIVOT casting the column directly to the appropriate type.